# Handling asynchronous function with webworker and promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, blocking

I try to handle the return of promise in order to get a blocking behavior when I call the asyncFunc defined in the code snippet below. In this function, I am using a webworker.

I am not an expert in JavaScript and the concept of promise is new for me. I tried to define an `asyncFunc` function into the block of my code. If I call this function after, I should normally have the code inside asyncFunc completely executed (but I am not sure).

The goal is to draw in a canvas (which is currently representing the gameboard) once **webworker has received the array to draw** (`HitCurrentvariable`) here, i.e in a synchronous way (drawing function is performed by `displayCurrentHit(HitCurrent)`).

```
else if (mode == 'computer') {
    // Call asynchronous function with promise
    function asyncFunc(HitCurrent) {
        // Return promise
        return new Promise( resolve => {
            // Creation of webworker
            let firstWorker = new Worker(workerScript);
            firstWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
                resolve(event.data);
            }   
            // Post current copy of HitCurrent, i.e HitCurrent
            firstWorker.postMessage([HitCurrent, HitCurrent.playerCurrent, maxNodes]);
        }).then(({result}) => {
            // Get back game board of webworker
            HitCurrent = result.HitResult;
            // Get back suggested hit computed by webworker
            [a,b] = HitCurrent.coordPlayable;
            console.log('Into promise : coordPlayable : (a,b) = ',a,b);
            // Drawing all lines from suggested hit (in 8 directions)
            for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
               exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, a, b, k, 'drawing');
            }   
            // Remove playable hits
            cleanHits('playable', HitCurrent);
            // Display current game
            displayCurrentHit(HitCurrent);
            // Up to there, first computer hit is good 
            // and game board is well drawn
            alert('Stop just after displayCurrentHit');
        })
    } 
    // Call asyncFunc : blocking ???
    asyncFunc(HitCurrent).then(console.log('Call async function'));
    // Prove asynchronuous of asyncFunc call
    alert('after asynFunc().then');
}
```

The call of asyncFunc is not blocking. How can I display current gameboard in a synchronous way using the `Promise` concept?

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make read and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance.

Comment: @CertainPerformance . Sorry, I only know the shortcut CTRL+K to indent code.

Comment: `async` functions do not block.

Comment: There is no magic way to make non-blocking asynchronous things into synchronous blocking operations in Javascript.  By definition, an `async` function returns a promise and by definition `.then()` calls it's handler asynchronously (non-blocking).

Comment: @trincot . In my case, is there a way to call drawing function `displayCurrentHit(HitCurrent);`once webworker has received the array to draw (`HitCurrent`variable here) ?

Comment: Not applicable here, but there is a way to make asynchronous code synchronous in Node.js using the sync methods in [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) but that's generally a bad idea anyway.

Comment: `.then(console.log('Call async function'))` then expects a function to call as argument. What you do is calling `console.log('Call async function')` immediately and passing the result (`undefined`) to `.then()`

Comment: @Thomas. ok, I didn't know

Comment: what's your point? to have this line "virtually a sync one"  `asyncFunc(HitCurrent).then(...);` ?

Comment: @quirimmo .  I would have thaught naively that it was a way to wait the complete execution of asyncFunc but this is not the case.

Comment: Are you really instantiating a new webworker at every game action? And without ever destroying it?

Comment: @Kaiido . Good remark, I didn't even think about it, how do you destroy it ?

Comment: Worker.terminate() but it would probably be better to keep it alive and send several messages to the same instance. Instantiating all contexts and  GCing every now and then is definitely not the best strategy either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong syntax resolving your promise.

`.then` accepts a function callback within, called when the promise will be resolved.

So in your case this code:

```
// Call asyncFunc : blocking ???
asyncFunc(HitCurrent).then(console.log('Call async function'));
// Prove asynchronuous of asyncFunc call
alert('after asynFunc().then');
```

Should be:

```
asyncFunc(HitCurrent).then(() => alert('after asynFunc()'));
```

Instead in order to write your code in a "sync way", you can use `async/await` in this way:

```js
function asyncFunc(HitCurrent) {
  // Return promise
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('finished'), 1000);
  }).then(data => {
    alert('promise resolved:' + data);
  })
}

(async () => {
  await asyncFunc();
  alert('after asynFunc().then');
})();
```

So you create an async function which awaits for the resolution of your promise and then alerts the values.

Comment: ok thanks ! I am going to try your solution. But why does -@Patrick Roberts told me that it was impossible in my case ? Regards

Comment: I think that he understood that you don't want simply to write your code like if it appears sync, but you want really that the code will be executed sync at OS level. But maybe asking him would be the best thing to do :)

Comment: Ok it works as expected ! really thanks. If I have well understood, we can circumevent the issue by using `(async)` and await `asyncFunc` : so the part `(async () => {
  await asyncFunc();
  alert('after asynFunc().then');
})();`is blocking, I mean, waiting the execution of all `asyncFunc`function,  isn't it ?